# Do WiFi APs on same channel still interfere at a farther range (-70+)?

Tags: wifi, interference, channel

I am aware that the most common channels for the 2.4Ghz band are (1 ,6 ,11). They are non-overlapping. I also know that channel 6 is the default for most routers, if not set to auto.

I am wondering whether or not WiFi interference is relevant if there are many APs on the same channel, but at a far range?

---

Let's say:

There are ten APs on channel 11, but 9 of them are at a range of -70 PWR or farther.

There are 3 APs on channel 6 and they are all at a range of -50 PWR or closer.

---

Channel 11 has many APs, but there is only one at close range.

Channel 6 has only three APs, but they are all at close range.

So, is it wiser for my WiFi to be set on channel 11 or 6 in the context of avoiding interference?

Answer (score 0):

In the situation you described I would put your AP on ch 1 since there aren't any other clients there.  If you're doing this in an enterprise setting you should really get a system that handles all of this for you (HP/Aruba has an excellent one if you can afford it).  If you're doing this at home or at a small business then just keep trying different channels until you find the one that works the best.

Comment: My last sentence meant to imply that there's no magic formula for this.  Try one channel and if you have problems try a different one.  Chances are there's going to be interference on every channel but how disruptive it is depends on so many factors that the only way to know is to try it.

Comment: Then what is the question?  Your original question asked which channel is wiser to avoid interference which is basically what you just said the question is *not*.

Comment: There are so many variables playing into it you can't really know without trying it.

Comment: The original question is in the context of the example given, not in general. Could you tell me a couple of these key variables that would make it so "you can't really know without trying it?" If so, please edit your answer and include in there. I'm going to delete my comments since they are not relevant info.

Comment: The big one is the amount of traffic on the interfering networks.  A network with a strong signal but no traffic won't interfere much because the only activity is the beacons whereas a weaker signal with intense traffic will interfere more.